# Track multiple window closes javascript (Have working code for one window)

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.closed

Does someone know the best solution to make the **code below work ('crosswindow')** to track multiple windows opened by the function openNew() ?

**It is currently only capable of tracking one window only.** I tried some stuff with objects but Im not an expert. All suggestions are welcome.

*Javascript:*

```
 function openNew(href){

    timer = setInterval('polling()',500);
    win = window.open(href, '_blank');

    url=href;
    openTime=0;
    clickTime= (new Date()).getTime();

}

function polling(){

     if (win && win.closed) {

        var closingTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        var diff = ((closingTime-clickTime)/1000);

        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log(url+" closed after " + diff + " secs");
    }  
}
```

*HTML*

```
<a href="http://google.com" onClick="openNew('http://google.com'); return false;" target="_blank">google</a>
<a href="https://facebook.com" onClick="openNew('https://facebook.com'); return false;" target="_blank">facebook</a>
```

**The goal in the end is to be able to open multiple new windows from the parent page and when a child window gets closed, its logged in the parent window.**

I have made a pen with a simulation of the console (to avoid infinity loop alerts )
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjGyQz?editors=101

Comment: Take a look at [wormhole](http://rubaxa.github.io/wormhole/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just need to wrap your call to polling in a closure, and pass in all of the variables to it, so it isn't overwriting the old ones:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJPqwm?editors=101

```
function openNew(href){
    var current = window.open(href, '_blank');
    var clickTime= (new Date()).getTime();
    (function(win, url, clickTime) {
        var timer = setInterval(function() { polling(win, timer, url, clickTime) },500);
    })(current, href, clickTime);       
}

function polling(win, timer, url, clickTime){
     if (win && win.closed) {
        var closingTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        var diff = ((closingTime-clickTime)/1000);
        clearInterval(timer);
        //replace console with div log
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += url+" closed after " + diff + " secs<br>";
    }  
}
```